# I am encrypting password using SHA2_256 hashbytes converter in SQL; now I want to see the orginal data

Tags: sql, asp.net-mvc, password-encryption, hashbytes

I tried this to convert data into encrypted data,

```
INSERT INTO userDetails (role, userName, name, password, statusId, isDeleted)
VALUES (@role, @username, @name,
        HASHBYTES('SHA2_256', @password COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CS_AS), 
        @status, 0)
```

The original data is '1234' but when I try this below code to retrieve the original data it returns

```
'18B84AE5B24E651842D52B8FC8E9FEF04BAB9E3169AE7A3D444BE7E691F9A2AF'
```

I tried this:

```
SELECT 
    CONVERT(VARCHAR(256), HASHBYTES('SHA2_256', password), 2) AS password  
FROM userDetails
```

How to get the original data of HASHBYTES 'SHA2_256' converted data?

Comment: You're not encrypting, you're hashing. They're very different things. You're not *intended* to be able to reverse a hashing process.

Comment: A hash cannot be reversed - what you need to do to validate a password is (1) hash this password provided using the same algorithm, and then (2) compare the **hashed** values - if they match, the password entered is correct

Comment: secure password hashing is more than a simple hash calc of the password. You need salt and iterations (10000+) to have also some cpu load to calculate the hashed password. It does not matter when you have to do it once for storing/comparing but will protect you from brute force attacking (for a while)

Comment: BTW asp.net has a build in passwordhasher [`PasswordHasher<TUser>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.identity.passwordhasher-1?view=aspnetcore-8.0) with anything you need

Answer (score -1):

Hash is rather a one way processing, however it looks like you have:

```
SELECT password FROM userDetails
```

Comment: Bro if i do this then it'll give data as 'ïy|ð-ûd–Ý]?Œv#Œœ=S,É\^×¨˜¦O'

Comment: OK, I have no idea

Comment: Your data has 32 bytes, it can be SHA256 already.
Just compare hashes, do not try to decrypt.